# Jupyter notebook how to wait for a non blocking call

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I have two functions:
- `draw()`: draws a figure using seaborn
- `print()`: prints out some text

If I call these functions in this order:

```
draw()
print()
```

The result of the print is always shown first then followed by the figure. Is it possible for the `print` call to wait until `draw` is finished?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose draw() here will launch a GUI, and then print() will be executed, but at the same time, the visual engine will still be rendering the plot. You then may just be looking for `time.sleep()`. The problem is that you need to know how long it is going to take for the engine to render your plot and this can vary from one system to another.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer I found, using `plt.show()` after each seaborn plot call:

```
for i in range(10):
    print('blah blah blah')
    sns.whateverplot()
    plt.show() # add this line
```

This will guarantee that the next print statement will not be printed until the previous drawing call is completed.